# Authentication manager is null after upgrading spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I am writing application in `spring boot` `2.7.4` version which has new version of `spring security`. So I need to rewrite my old code to the new one.
Here is my old security configuration with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class AppWebConfig(
    val customUserDetailsService: CustomUserDetailsService,
    val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    val tokensService: TokensService
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            //urls permissions...
            .addFilter(AppAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), tokensServicee))
    }

}
```

And here is the new code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class AppWebConfig(
    val tokensService: TokensService,
) {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager? {
        return authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    protected fun fitlerChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        val authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager::class.java)

        return http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            //urls permissions...
            .addFilter(AppAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, tokensService))
            .build()
    }
```

Here is the `AppAuthorizationFilter` which hasn't changed in both versions and where the `authenticationManager` is used:

```
class AppAuthorizationFilter(
    authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    tokensService: TokensService,
) : BasicAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager) {
    private val tokensService: TokensService

    init { this.tokensService = tokensService }

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        chain: FilterChain,
    ) {
        val header = request.getHeader(Objects.requireNonNull(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
        if (header != null) {
            val authorizedUser = tokensService.parseAccessToken(header)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authorizedUser
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

And the problem is with `authenticationManager` from `AppWebConfig`. I get the error that this its null.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: authenticationManager must not be null at com.app.security.config.WebConfig.fitlerChain(WebConfig.kt:68)
```

I tried the solution I showed above by getting `authenticationManager` from shared objects `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager::class.java)` but it does not work as you can see.

I solved the problem by getting `authenticationManager` from `WebApplicationContext` but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it

```
val authenticationManager = applicationContext.getBean("authenticationManager") as AuthenticationManager
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this annotation `(@Primary)` to you authenticationManager bean. If didn't work, then go with the solution you mentioned.

```
@Bean
@Primary // try to add this
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager? {
    return authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please access the authentication manager once you build it or after it builds.

```
       public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, ResourceProtectAware protectAware) throws Exception {
            protectAware.addUrlAuthorization(http);
            http.cors();
            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
           // http.addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationFilter(configuration.getAuthenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            DefaultSecurityFilterChain build = http.build();
//access it after you build. 
            AuthenticationManager sharedObject = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
            return build;
        }
```